# java.util.NoSuchElementException for reading in integer.txt

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a program that receives a 6x7 list of integers and stores then in an array. However I'm getting a  java.util.NoSuchElementException, I've been out of practice for a while so I may be sloppy with my syntax and I'm wondering what I am doing wrong.

This is an example of a .txt file being read.

```
0 1 0 3 1 6 1
0 1 6 8 6 0 1
5 5 2 1 8 2 9
6 5 6 1 1 9 1
1 5 6 1 4 0 7
3 5 3 4 4 0 7
```

my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{

    System.out.println(new File("num1.txt").getAbsolutePath());
    int i;
    int j;

    i=0;
    j=0;
    int [][]connect4Array;
    connect4Array= new int [6][7];
    int [][]list;



    Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File("num1.txt"));



    while(readFile.hasNextInt())
    {
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
        connect4Array[i][j]=readFile.nextInt();
            for(j=0;j<6;j++)
            {
            connect4Array[i][j]=readFile.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(connect4Array[1][2]);

    list=connect4Array;

    isConsecutiveFour(list);




    readFile.close();

}
 list=connect4Array;

    isConsecutiveFour(list);




    readFile.close();

}

public static boolean isConsecutiveFour(int[][] values) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    boolean connected4;
    connected4=false;
    int cntr1;
    int cntr2;
    cntr1=0;
    cntr2=0;
    int i;
    int horizontalMatch;
    int verticalMatch;
    int diagonalMatch;
    horizontalMatch=0;
    i=0;



    //check for horizontal matches
    for(cntr1=0;cntr1<6;cntr1++)
    {
        for(cntr2=0;cntr2<7;cntr2++)
        {

            if(values[cntr1][cntr2]==values[cntr1][cntr2])
            {
                cntr2++;
                if (values[cntr1][cntr2]==values[cntr1][cntr2])
                {
                    cntr2++;
                    if (values[cntr1][cntr2]==values[cntr1][cntr2])
                    {
                        cntr2++;
                        if (values[cntr1][cntr2]==values[cntr1][cntr2])
                        {
                            connected4=true;
                            horizontalMatch=+1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   

    System.out.println(connected4);
    System.out.println("Horizontal Matches= "+horizontalMatch);



    return(connected4);
}
```

the full error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
at assignment5.Assignment5.isConsecutiveFour(Assignment5.java:90)
at assignment5.Assignment5.main(Assignment5.java:49)
```

edit:

I wasn't planning on sharing the rest of my code, but after fixing the error in the for loop, it noticed another in a different part of my code with the same error. If you guys could help again that'd be great

Comment: In the first iteration, `j=0` and the inner `j` loop goes from 0 to 6, so `connect4Array[0][0]` is calculated twice, which results in a shift by 1 and eventually the exception you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time through the outer loop, you're reading 35 values, because you're iterating the second loop 5 times, and each iteration reads one value, then iterates the third loop 6 times.  And you have 42 values in the file.  So you're finishing the file partway through the second iteration of the outer loop, then getting the error when you're trying to read the 43rd value.

You probably don't need the outer loop at all, or the first line inside the second loop.  The following may do what you want.  Notice how I've changed the termination conditions on each loop, to accommodate your 6 rows and 7 columns.

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   for ( j = 0; j < 7; j++){
      connect4Array[i][j]=readFile.nextInt();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question, but I have a new error later in my code now. I edited my original post if you wouldn't mind taking a look at it for me.

Comment: If you have a new question, then you should ask it as a new question, rather than editing one that is already asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with `connect4Array[i][j]=readFile.nextInt();` in outer loop which the value of `j` at there is always `0` as you defined before loops but in inner loop it'll get the value of j defined in for statement also you need to increase the borders (i and j):

```
for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=6;j++)
    {
    connect4Array[i][j]=readFile.nextInt();
    }
}
```